# Inconveniente con funcion BuscarV (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup con SharePoint) en VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia, por medio de la presente deseo pedirles el favor si me  pueden indicar por que razón la siguiente funcion Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup que es la función BuscarV en VBA al momento de mandarle los siguientes parametro o tener la siguiente estructura:

```
Dim celda1 As Double
valbusc1 = Hoja2.Cells(i, j)
celda1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(valbusc1, 'https://empresa.sharepoint.com/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/CM/PLAN DE RUTAS/[PLAN DE ENVIOS 16 JULIO 2022.xls]OPERADORES'!$A$1:$E$65536;5;0)
```

Me muestra el siguiente error: Error de compilación - Error de sintaxis

me envía a la siguiente pagina (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/syntax-error)

Me he roto la cabeza viendo como solucionar  el inconveniente de sintaxis pero desafortunadamente no he podido dar con la solución
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba con EVALUATE

Comment: Los Argumentos de la función se separan con coma, no con punto y coma.
Prueba:
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(valbusc1, 'https://empresa.sharepoint.com/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/CM/PLAN DE RUTAS/[PLAN DE ENVIOS 16 JULIO 2022.xls]OPERADORES'!$A$1:$E$65536,5,0)
Y ten en cuenta que buscará el valor en la columna A

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, el inconveniente que ahora se me presenta es el siguiente:

tengo en excel la siguiente función:
VALIDACIONES = IFERROR(LOOKUPVALUE('BaseOcupacionSemanal'[ConcatenarValidaciones],
'https://cmconsultores.sharepoint.com/sites/POST-OPERACIONAL/Documentos compartidos/
5. Informes semanales/7. Del 18 de julio al 24 de julio de 2022/INSUMOS SEMANA 29/
VALIDACIONES/[Consolidado Validaciones semana 29.xlsx]Hoja1'!$U:$Y,5,0),0)

pero me muestra error marcándome en color rojo a partir de la Url https, Gracias por la ayuda.